# I'm trying to setup a few different multidimensional arrays and cant figure out why this isnt working

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

Arrays a and b are fine, c is saying too many initializer values, and d is assigning -858993460 to every field. Any comments and help is appreciated. This is for a class so I would like to understand the situation please!

```
int a[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
int b[2][3] = { {9, 8}, {7, 6, 5} };
int c[3][2] = { { 4, 4, 4 },{ 7, 7 } };
int d[3][3] = { {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1} };
```

Comment: `int b[2][3]` means "2 arrays of 3 ints" not "1 array of 2 ints followed by 1 array of 3 ints". Once you understand this you should be able to see what's wrong. Multidimensional arrays cannot hold arrays of different sizes, if you need different sizes in the same container you'll need to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or a flat array and manual index calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of the array `c` have type `int[2]`. Thus each element of the array must be initialized at most with two initializers.

Instead of

```
int c[3][2] = { { 4, 4, 4 },{ 7, 7 } };
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

write for example

```
int c[3][2] = { { 4, 4 },{ 7, 7 } };
                ^^^^^^^^
```

Array d is initialized correctly.

```
int d[3][3] = { {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1} };
```

Its initialization is equivalent to the following

```
int d[3][3] = 
{ 
   {1, 1, 1}, 
   {1, 1, 1},
   {0, 0, 0} 
};
```

It seems you get an incorrect value because you are using a wrong index when you access the array.

Here is a demonstrative program written in C++ that shows the arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = 
    { 
        { 1, 2 }, 
        { 3, 4 } 
    };
    int b[2][3] = 
    { 
        { 9, 8 }, 
        { 7, 6, 5 } 
    };
    int c[3][2] = 
    { 
        { 4, 4 },
        { 7, 7 } 
    };
    int d[3][3] = 
    { 
        { 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1 } 
    };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &row : b )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &row : c )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &row : d )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 
3 4 

9 8 0 
7 6 5 

4 4 
7 7 
0 0 

1 1 1 
1 1 1 
0 0 0
```

Elements of the arrays that were not initialized explicitly were initialized by zero implicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your response so quickly. This definitely helped me figure it out. I understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks again!